# ArtifactResolve signed twice

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I am having trouble creating an ArtifactResolve because it seems to get signed twice when I try to bind it. Perhaps my setup is wrong?

In the end, the XML document has two Signature nodes.

```
Saml2Configuration samlConfig = new Saml2Configuration
            {
                Issuer = "issuer.com",
                SigningCertificate = cert,
                SignatureAlgorithm = "mysignalg",
                SignAuthnRequest = true,
            };

Saml2ArtifactResolve artifactResolve = new Saml2ArtifactResolve(samlConfig)
            {
                IdAsString = "_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"),
                Artifact = artifact
            };

artifactResolve.Validate();
Saml2PostBinding binding = new Saml2PostBinding();
return binding.Bind(artifactResolve);
```

Update:

When using ArtifactBinding, I get a null reference exception.

```
Saml2Configuration samlConfig = new Saml2Configuration
            {
                Issuer = "msomething.nl",
                SigningCertificate = cert,
                SignatureAlgorithm = SingatureAlgorithm,
                SignAuthnRequest = true
            };

Saml2ArtifactResolve artifactResolve = new Saml2ArtifactResolve(samlConfig)
            {
                IdAsString = "_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"),
                Artifact = artifact,
                Destination = new Uri("http://mydestination"),
            };

            artifactResolve.Validate();
            Saml2ArtifactBinding binding = new Saml2ArtifactBinding();
            binding.RelayState = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            return binding.Bind(artifactResolve);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot bind the `Artifact Resolve` with a `POST binding`, you need to use a `Artifact binding`. Please se the [IdP sample](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestIdPCore/Controllers/AuthController.cs#L179).

And the relaying party [artifact sample](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/tree/master/test/TestWebAppCoreArtifact).

Comment: Hi Anders, thank you for taking the time to reply. I have already tried using the ArtifactBinding, but I do get a System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. error. I updated the question with the code.

Comment: You should not do a validation during creation. Please change the code according to the sample code https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/blob/master/test/TestIdPCore/Controllers/AuthController.cs#L181